# If the permissions on a file were set so that everyone could read from or write to the file, how would that be represented symbolically

Tags: linux, networking, ls, computer-science

If the permissions on a file were set so that everyone could read from or write to the file, how would that be represented symbolically (within the output of an 'ls -l' command)?

Comment: You mean like `rw-rw-rw-` or 0666?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean by "symbolically", but they *are* represented in various tools in various ways:

- [`rw-rw-rw-`](https://wiki.debian.org/Permissions#Human-readable_form)
- [`666` or `0666`](https://wiki.debian.org/Permissions#Section_2:_UNIX_permissions_explained)
- `a=rw`

See `man chmod` for more information.